# My gulp task return me always the same option

Tags: server, gulp, task

We need to select by prompt which is the enviromment selected by the user.
I have this code:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean'); 
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); 
var rename = require('gulp-rename'); 
var gutil = require('gulp-util'); 
var order = require("gulp-order");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var ftp = require('gulp-ftp');
var prompt = require('gulp-prompt');



gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  gulp.src('app/dist/custom.js')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
        type:'text',
        name: 'env',
        message: 'Where dou you want toy deploy? ( stage / live / test )',
        validate: function(env){

            if(env === 'STAGE' || 'stage'){
                 gutil.log('STAGE deployment');
                 return true;
            }
            if(env === 'LIVE' || 'live'){
               gutil.log('LIVE deployment');
               return true;
            }
            if(env == 'TEST' || 'test'){
              gutil.log('TEST deployment');
              return true;
            }

        }
    }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['deploy']);
```

But if someone would like to select any enviromment... the callback always says...
'STAGE deployment'.

But if I change the code, it works:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean'); 
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); 
var rename = require('gulp-rename'); 
var gutil = require('gulp-util'); 
var order = require("gulp-order");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var ftp = require('gulp-ftp');
var prompt = require('gulp-prompt');



gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  gulp.src('app/dist/custom.js')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
        type:'text',
        name: 'env',
        message: 'Where dou you want toy deploy? ( stage / live / test )',
        validate: function(env){

            if(env === 'STAGE'){
                 gutil.log('STAGE deployment');
                 return true;
            }
            if(env === 'LIVE'){
               gutil.log('LIVE deployment');
               return true;
            }
            if(env == 'TEST'){
              gutil.log('TEST deployment');
              return true;
            }

        }
    }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['deploy']);
```

But I want the options with uppercase & lowercase... Anyone looks the issue?

BR,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test for equality on both sides of the `||`:

```
if(env === 'STAGE' || env === 'stage'){
   gutil.log('STAGE deployment');
   return true;
}
if(env === 'LIVE' || env === 'live'){
  gutil.log('LIVE deployment');
  return true;
}
if(env == 'TEST' || env === 'test'){
  gutil.log('TEST deployment');
  return true;
}
```

Evaluating a non-empty string like `'stage'` in a boolean context evaluates to [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), which makes your entire OR-expression `env === 'STAGE' || 'stage'` evaluate to `true` regardless of what value `env` has.

Comment: sorry it's true, basic js, yesterday was to tired, jajajaj thanks Sven